# NAO robot V4 - wrist motors issue

Tags: nao-robot

I have two NAO Robots V4 , one of them has no motors nor sensors in his wrist, is it possible to replace his wrist with the 2nd robot wrist which has motors ? however, the wrist motors don't appear in choregraphe. should I define these motors or what should I do to make them recognized in his system ?

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have some hardware issue, so just contact the support. There's a form on the company website who produces this robots. Or try something like support@aldebaran.com